# Passport-SAML: entryPoint / auth request header overridden

Tags: node.js, iis, passport.js, saml

Alright you gurus, I need some help / understanding of what is happening here. I'm leveraging passport and passport-saml to do single sign on for my application. I have been able to get things working locally on my development machine, but when I deploy to our staging server, something is amiss and not leveraging the entryPoint URL that I have configured...

Example code:

```
return new Strategy(
    {
        callbackUrl: "https://my.domain.com/staging/api/login/callback",
        entryPoint: "https://my.idp.com/affwebservices/public/saml2sso",
        issuer: "my.domain.com",
        cert: "THE SECRET SAUCE"
    },
    function(profile, done) {
        // .....
    }
)

// ROUTES ----------------------------------------------------------------------

app.get('/api/login', passport.authenticate("saml", { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }) );

app.post('/api/login/callback', passport.authenticate("saml", { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }), (request, response) => {
    // .....
});
```

When I run this locally, as stated, it works and I see the following SAML request being made:

```
https://my.idp.com/affwebservices/public/saml2sso?SAMLRequest=.....
```

However, once deployed, the entryPoint URL domain is overriden with the staging domain:

```
https://my.domain.com/affwebservices/public/saml2sso?SAMLRequest=.....
```

I'm noticing that the request generated is assuming authority to my.domain.com rather than utilizing my.idp.com:

[image: Wrong authority]

I will say that the only difference between the development server and staging/prod server is that staging/prod is utilizing IIS as a reverse proxy to route incoming traffic based on URL string (i.e. my.domain.com/production, my.domain.com/staging). I've enabled CORS on the node server, which was how I got it working on the development server in the first place, as well as tried configuring IIS to allow for it too...

Stumped at this point. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well after enough headbanging, I found a way to resolve the issue. As suspected, it was with IIS, and solution I implemented was a URL redirect:

[image]

I don't know if this is the most robust solution; so if someone else stumbled upon this, feel free to reach out. Either way, this works.